# User profile synchronization - AD - "&" character triggers update on users

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, user-profile-property, term-store, ad

When doing a sync against AD almost every user get updated. And this happens every time I'm doing a sync!

[image]

When I look at FIM it looks like SPS-Deparment detects changes because AD has a different &-character than that SharePoint stores in the termset. look at picture

[image]

I know that SPS-Department is a termset so I think that terms have to be in UTF-8 but I'm not sure about what char is in the AD.

Is there a workaround?  I cannot change every "&" char in AD because they have many systems that relies on AD.

Another question.. is "&" a legal character in AD?